# How do I run animate() once the page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a menu item that is animated in the following fiddle by clicking a link, but I actually want the background color fade animation to start once the page has loaded (without the need to click a link). How do I change the code in the following fiddle to animate once the page has loaded?

The code I have currently is:

```
$("a").click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
    $("#menu-item-9032 a")
      .animate( { backgroundColor: "#00afee", color: "#363a47" }, 2000 )
      .animate( { backgroundColor: "transparent", color: "#363a47" }, 2000 );
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fe8Jy/500/

If I replace `$("a").click(function(e) {` with `$(document).ready(function() {` nothing happens, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? If you left the first line of the function unchanged, then it's probably complaining that there is no `e` that you could call any methods on ...

Comment: And what's the `for` loop for?

Comment: @CBroe I'm guessing so that it pulses twice.

Comment: @mpen: Right, forgot animations are queued by default.

Comment: I think you forget to delete `preventDefault`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fe8Jy/502/

Comment: Thanks everyone. yes removing that preventdefault does the trick - thanks! And yes it's a pulse effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have created a syntax error. Code works fine with jQuery's ready:

http://jsfiddle.net/tks2sobo/

```
$(function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
        $("#menu-item-9032 a")
            .animate( { backgroundColor: "#00afee", color: "#363a47" }, 2000 )
            .animate( { backgroundColor: "transparent", color: "#363a47" }, 2000 );
    }
});
```

Comment: Any ideas why the background color it fades to seems to be white, when it should be transparent?

Comment: @Metzed Not sure... I guess jQuery animate doesn't properly support `transparent`? You can try with `rgba` or you can put the text into a different element and fade with `opacity`.

Comment: thanks. The original answer worked well thank you and thanks so much for posting that CSS3 solution. I've now used that instead.